# Does this motherboard support two graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I've just bought new gaming PC with an [Intel<sup>®</sup> H81 Chipset (Intel<sup>®</sup> DH82H81 PCH)](http://ark.intel.com/products/75016/Intel-DH82H81-PCH). I already have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 and I want to add another 3d graphics card. Is it possible to support another one? My power supply is 350 Watts.

Comment: That link is to a CPU not a motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could I don't suggest you to add another graphics card with a PSU of 350 Watts.

Comment: maybe i can replace the psu 350 with a higher one ... if this is the only one probleme

Comment: That not the only problem, you need to specify: CPU, the socket, operating system, ram, type of case, mother board, case fan  ...

Comment: well this is my actual computer with all spesification if you would to know : http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883229563

Comment: Given the specifications you gave me I would suggest a 400 ~ 450 Watts PSU 80+. I dont recommend you to overclock in that PC, also I dont know how many fans it has. In a nutshell: for that price you could build a better one.

Comment: really, i didn't get it yet i can cancel my order, have u some suggestions about ?i will be so greatful

Comment: depends of what you need, GAMER, LOW-BUDGET, SERVER, ...

Comment: i think if i choose GAMER my computer has already riched most of games need didn't it? if it's not can u suggest me some good deals please

Comment: Do you know how to build PCs?

Comment: i have never did it before, but i had a desktop pc  wich i fixed it so many times

Comment: well, in this website http://pcpartpicker.com/builds/?sort=rating you can find amazing builds made by other people and sort them based in your criteria

Comment: thank u very much , this could help me a lot, unfortunately i'm not in the usa i will just order it from here(Morocco) if there's not a big difference,u know  to ship it all, it will be very expensive

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest adding up the power requirements of all the hardware components you have.   To include but not limited to:

- CPU
- Motherboard
- Video Card(s)
- RAM
- Hard Drives
- Optical Drives
- Fans
- and anything else drawing power

If the total power needed is lower than what the power supply puts out then you should be fine.  If not or if it is close then I would recommend upgrading the power supply as well.

Comment: ok thank you, but if i could upgrade  my psu to higher, with my actual components can i add another graphic card ? is it possible or not

Comment: Oh yeah definitely.  Just make sure you purchase the correct PSU (right form factor, same motherboard connections, and correct/enough power connections).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your motherboard can support only one graphics card(as there is only one pci-express slot), as @Rosenthal said, Even if you could I don't suggest you to add another graphics card with a PSU of 350 Watts. Even you managed to connect the second graphics card to your system my means of any extended board or something, it is difficult to work both cards simultaneously. and this link will be also helpful to you

[Can I use both my internal and external graphics card in same system?](https://superuser.com/questions/737546/can-i-use-both-my-internal-and-external-graphics-card-in-same-system)